# Issue with Publishing Image Field

Tags: 2010, page-layout, custom-field-types

I have a custom Publishing Image field defined as

```
 <Field ID="{621EC4B5-457F-4B64-B2F1-6F568F6BFA60}" Name="ContentImage1"
 SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3" StaticName="ContentImage1" 
 Group="My Custom Columns" DisplayName="ContentImage1" Type="Image" 
 Format="Image" RichText="TRUE" RichTextMode="FullHtml" IsolateStyles="TRUE" 
 Sortable="FALSE" />
```

When using the publishing image field in a page layout it adds extra closing divs which breaks the layout of the page.  Weirdly if you then edit the page it fixes it - it fixes the edited page but not the content deployed version of the page (unless you edit it too - which is pointless as it will be overwritten next time the page is deployed)

I've tried using the RichImageField control and the FieldValue control both of which render

```
<img alt="Learning" height="200" src="/Learn/PublishingImages/theatre880.jpg" 
width="880" style="border:0px solid" /></div></div>
```

This was proven by wrapping the SharePoint controls in a `<span>....</span>`  and still finding the offending divs in there.

Any ideas?

Is there any way (in a publishing page layout) to get just the url of the image rather than the whole tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way around this is to create a custom control that inherits RichImageField and overrides the rendering (e.g. RenderFieldForDisplay method).